# Create SCNPlane with the size of SCNView

Tags: ios, scenekit

How do I create a `SCNPlane` / `SCNBox` which has the same size of `SCNView`? I think this can be done by adjusting the position of `SCNCamera`. But how do we make it standard that will work for `SCNView` with any size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got the answer that I am looking for;

1. `let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: self.bounds.size.width, height: self.bounds.size.height)` create the plane with your `SCNView` size.
2. Find the camera Z position using following calculation;`((self.bounds.height / 2.0) / tanf((GLKMathDegreesToRadians(Float(fov/2.0))))` ; Will get fov from `cameraNode.camera?.fieldOfView`